# Disabling HTMLencode in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using DataTable to populate data in GridView in ASP.NET
I am trying to place a line break in a cell inside the DataGrid View
I used

```
   "data1+<br>+data2"
```

to place a line break.**I am manipulating this data from C# which is being generated dynamically.**
Because of HTML encoding 
 is replaced as

```
 lt;brgt;
```

So please tell me how to disable that html encoding if possible for that gridView.

Comment: Use `<asp:TemplateField/>`

Comment: @Bharadwaj I didnot get you

Comment: @codeCaster Is this a duplicate? Can you show me the answer then?

Comment: Click the link on top of your question, the duplicate contains 4 answers. If you think none of them answers your question, please update your question with how exactly you print the data to your DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TemplateField` allows you to add `html` inside a cell, as

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutogenerateColumns = "false">
 <columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="col_name" HeaderText="Header"/>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         '<%#Eval("data1")%>'
          <br/>
         '<%#Eval("data2")%>'
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 <columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: How can I place it inside a data cell?

Comment: `TemplateField` itself a data cell.

Comment: I think you are populating using `BoundedField`, replace it with the above code, if you have `data1` and `data2` as separate columns in your datatable.

Comment: wHERE CAN i FIND THAT IN MY vISUAL sTUDIO  under the designer->grid view->properties?

Comment: WOW. Switch to `Source` mode for your `.aspx` or `.ascx` file. For `GridView`, set `AutogenerateColumns = "false"`. Then add all coloumns you want, including the above.

Comment: Data source for that data grid view is going to be a data table.

Comment: No problem. `data1` and `data2` should be columns in that data table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56712/discussion-between-abhinav-konda-and-bharadwaj).

Answer (score 1):

There is a option available in Boundfield of your grid view. HtmlEncode="false"

The code in my case

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="timeStamp" HeaderText="timeStamp" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Comment: I didnot find the BoundField in GridView properties I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: BoundField  is part of Gridview columns. Can you post the part of your code, to get a clear picture?